# AlertDialog - do not dismiss on item click

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

OK so I am creating an ArrayAdapter and using it in my Alert Dialog because I don't want to show the default radio buttons on SingleItemSelection dialog.

Instead I want to change the background of the item that is selected, and then when the user presses the positive button I will perform the action related to the item that has been selected.

```
    private void showAlertDialog()
    {
        final String[] options = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dialog_options);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, options);
        
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("My Dialog");
        
        dialogBuilder.setAdapter(adapter, new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item clicked at index " + which, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
// Here I need to change the background color of the item selected and prevent the dialog from being dismissed
            }
        });
    
        //String strOkay = getString(R.string.okay);
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", null); // TODO
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null); // nothing simply dismiss
    
        AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

There are two problems I'm trying to tackle.

> How do I prevent the dialog from being dismissed when the user clicks on an item
>
> How do I change the background of the item that has been selected when the user clicks on it

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To prevent dialog from dismissing on item click you can use **AdapterView**.OnItemClickListener instead of **DialogInterface**.OnClickListener.

Like this:

```
dialogBuilder.setAdapter(adapter, null);
...
AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(
new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
// do your stuff here
}
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to make an AlertDialog with an item list and a text input. This answer allowed me to keep the dialog open after the user touched an item.

Answer (score 11):

1. You can set custom ListView as content of AlertDialog and set OnItemClickListener

   ```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   String[] items = ...;
   ListView list = new ListView(this);
   list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items));
   list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos, long id) {
               ...
           }
       });
   builder.setView(list);
   ```

   and then save reference to dialog

   ```
   mDialog = builder.show();
   ```

   in order to dismiss it if necessary

   ```
   mDialog.dismiss();
   ```

Comment: This doesn't work on Android 4.0.1. The listview is disabled. When you leave the app and return it will be enabled again. I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I prevent the dialog from being dismissed when the user clicks on an item
>
> How do I change the background of the item that has been selected when the user clicks on it

Here is example

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String listFragmentTag = "listFragmentTag";
private static final String data[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};

public MainActivity() {
    super();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void btnClick(View v) {
    ListFragment lf = new ListFragment();
    lf.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), listFragmentTag);
}

public static class ListFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override @NonNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setTitle("List")
                .setItems(data, null)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null); // pass your onClickListener instead of null

        // to keep dialog open after click on item
        AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
        ad.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            private int colorOrg = 0x00000000;
            private int colorSelected = 0xFF00FF00;
            private View previousView;
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // restoring color of previous view
                if(previousView != null) {
                    previousView.setBackgroundColor(colorOrg);
                }
                // changing items's BG color
                view.setBackgroundColor(colorSelected);
                previousView = view;
            }
        });

        return ad;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score -3):

1. You can use setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false) or setCanceleable(false).
2. Set selector for the root element tag of the dialog layout xml.